# How to send a lead with a lookup field to dynamics CRM (using PHP and AlexaCRM toolkit)?

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, alexacrm-toolkit

I'm using AlexaCRM and I tried sending a lead with a lookup field. I don't have any problems with other fields. This is my code:

```
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Client as OrganizationService;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Settings;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Entity\EntityReference;

try {

$options = [
    'serverUrl' => 'urldelcrm',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'authMode' => 'OnlineFederation',
];

$serviceSettings = new Settings( $options );
$service = new OrganizationService( $serviceSettings);
$lead = $service->entity('lead');
$lead->firstname = $data['fields']['name'];

//...Lookup field:
$guid = "1111111-1111-111-11-11" // guid campaign
$lead->campaignid = new EntityReference('campaign', $guid );
$leadId = $lead->create();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
   // echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But when I peek in the CRM the field, "campaignid" is empty. Then I printed the `$lead` variable and the "campaignid" is empty too.
Also I tried,

```php
$lead->campaignid = $service->entity( 'campaign', $guid );
```

Instead of `EntityReference('campaign', $guid)`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What do you get when you printed `$lead`?

Comment: I guess you were passing a valid campaign id and not $guid = "1111111-1111-111-11-11"

Comment: @weegee i get an array inside of "AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Entity Object"
 with all variables i can use (retrieved from the CRM) and the data i setted, except the campaignid that is empty, example:      

       [emailaddress1] => Array
                (
                    [Value] => test@test.com
                    [Changed] => 1
                )

Comment: @ArunVinoth yes, of course.

Comment: @EmiPainkiller for testing do one thing, go to any campaign record, get its guid so that you have valid guid of campaign and then `new EntityReference('campaign', $guid );` I am not sure for PHP but you need guid of type Guid which in c# can be done with `Guid.Parse("1234-5678-so on")`

Comment: @AnkUser yes, I did that. i get the guid from a valid campaign and set it in the parameters of EntyReference. And nothing..